# discrete stable distribution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Suppose that $g\sim N(0,I_n)$ is a standard Gaussian vector in $n$-dimensional space, and $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of full row rank, then $Ag\sim N(0, AA^T)$ is again a Gaussian vector.

I am wondering if there is some discrete distribution such that when $g$ is drawn from the distribution, and $A$ is an integer matrix, $Ag$ is close to some distribution in the same family as $g$.

Can anyone point me to some reference?

Comment: It seems you can take any set of discrete distributions and take the closure of the set under this operation to obtain a family with this property.  Whether it is a useful family is another matter.